# I'm having trouble with 'while' in python

Tags: python

Here is my code:

```
while c2 != 1 or 2:
    c2 = input('<1.Enter the kitchen> <2.Exit the house> ')
```

I was trying to make a text-based rpg, but this part kept stuffing up! I wanted the console to keep asking for the input until the 'c2' variable was 1 or 2, but it kept looping! What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

change `while c2 != 1 or 2:`
to

```
while c2 != 1 and c2 != 2:
```

or

```
while c2 not in (1, 2):
```

Answer (score 1):

first, there's a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10764007/python-while-loop-the-and-operator-is-not-working) (it's about **and**. same as **or**)

second, when doing a multiply conditions you need to separate them like so:

```
while c2 != 1 and c2 != 2:
    c2 = input('<1.Enter the kitchen> <2.Exit the house> ')
```

notice that the logics you use `while c2 != 1 or 2` becomes a different logic expression

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to be doing a lot of these type of inputs, then it might make more sense to make a function to deal with this as follows:

```
def get_response(prompt, replies):
    while True:
        answer = input(prompt)
        if answer in replies:
            return answer

c2 = get_response('<1.Enter the kitchen> <2.Exit the house> ', ['1', '2'])
```